# openX alternatives, maybe self hosted

Tags: openx

I've been using openX self hosted ad management software lately, but it's sooo slow.

Goal: I need to be able to show an ad for 10 clicks then disable the ad, and do it daily.

Problem: When I set openX at 10 clicks per day, its so slow that it may disable the ad after like 30 clicks instead, that's no good.

Can anybody recommend an ad management software that can do what I want, and is free or cheap?  Im looking at adzerk atm, which is free, but my campaigns are pending, and thats silly.

Im on the hunt for an openX alternative.

Answer (score 6):

Revive Adserver : http://www.revive-adserver.com

Best & Free Open Source Ad Server (Previously known as OpenX Source).

Currently Revive Ad Server  Team maintains the code & continuously fixing bugs , security updates ,adding  new features etc .

You can scale more than 1 Billion Impressions per Day using cluster setup

Example :

https://www.serverstack.com/managed-apps/openx

You can upgrade the current OpenX source 2.8.X version to Revive Ad Server

Also easily customize the source code as per 10 click per day

Regards,

Chinnu.G

Answer (score 5):

Broadstreet: http://broadstreetads.com

We've moved quite a few high-traffic publishers over from OpenX with an automated migration. We were big fans of OpenX in the past, but finally faced the reality of its technology stack (including Revive's) and built an alternative: http://broadstreetads.com/blog/why-openx-is-slow/